# Yii2: How to access _POST method data

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Sending form data from one action to another

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' =>'site/roomsearch','method' => 'post']); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'arrival')->label(false) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'departure')->label(false) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Send', ['class' => 'btn btn-white']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

index page has the above form from which sending data to `actionRoomsearch()`

**actionindex():**

```
 public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = new \yii\base\DynamicModel(['arrival','departure','adult','child']);

                if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
            {
                $arrival = $model->arrival;
                $departure = $model->departure;
                return $this->redirect([
                              'roomsearch',
                              'arrival' => $arrival ,  
                              'departure' => $departure
                            ]);
            }

        return $this->render('index', ['model'=>$model]);
    }
```

**actionroomsearch():**

```
{
        $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
        $arrival = $post['arrival'];
        $departure = $post['departure'];

        return $this->render('roomsearch',[
              'arrival' =>$arrival,
            'departure' => $departure,
            ]);
    }
```

How to display `arrival` and `departure` in `roomsearch` page?

Created model using `\yii\base\DynamicModel`

Comment: are arrival and departure array ?or just a variable ?

Comment: just variable, contains date

Comment: try printing `arrival` or `deprature` in `roomsearch` page.

Comment: getting error `Undefined index: arrival` in `actionroomsearch`

Comment: Its becoz your POST doesn't contain `arrival` . I don't think its possible to access post data after redirecting. If you can pass it as get parameters check my answer.

Comment: is there any alternative to pass form data from one action to another, apart from `redirecting`

Comment: i just need to pass form data from index to roomsearch page, any wiki to guide me?

Comment: try calling your second action as function. ie `$this->actionroomsearch()` rather than redirecting.Im not sure about it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as you are redirecting from one action to another , you cant access POST data in the second action. But you can pass it as get parameters

```
return $this->redirect(\yii\helpers\Url::to([
     '/you_controller/your_action',
     'arrival' => $arrival ,  
     'departure' => $departure
]));
```

In your Second Action

```
$arrival = yii::$app->request->get('arrival');
$departure = yii::$app->request->get('departure');
```

Comment: its not working did this `$arrival = $model->arrival;
                $departure = $model->departure;
                return $this->redirect([
                              'roomsearch',
                              'arrival' => $arrival ,  
                              'departure' => $departure
                            ]);` getting nothing

Comment: in page` <?php echo $arrival ?> ` but not showing anything

Comment: You sure $model->arrival has value in it ?

Comment: Also in your actionroomsearch   `$arrival = yii::$app->request->get('arrival');`  ryt ?

Comment: `public function actionRoomsearch()
    {
        $arrival = yii::$app->request->get('arrival');
        $departure = yii::$app->request->get('departure');

        return $this->render('roomsearch',[
            
            'arrival' =>$arrival,
            'departure' => $departure,
            ]);
    }`

Comment: check your url after redirection , does it have arrival and departure parameters ?

Comment: before submitting the form `http://localhost/NewHotel/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2Findex&1%5Bclass%5D=smoothScroll` and after submitting the form `http://localhost/NewHotel/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2Froomsearch` it simply redirecting the page not sending the parameters

Comment: Edited the answer please check it.

Comment: `Url::to(['SiteController/actionroomsearch'])` is this right?

Comment: No , just ids are needed ie , `Url::to(['site/roomsearch'])`

Comment: i did that but its not working still getting the same URL after submitting the form

Comment: Ok this is weird. I did the same in my local and its working. Try this  `Url::to(['/site/roomsearch?arrival='.$arrival.'&departure='.$departure])`

Comment: `http://localhost/NewHotel/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2Froomsearch%3Farrival%3D%26departure%3D` its not getting the value also getting an error `page not found`

Comment: Your sure value is not null in $model->arrival. Before redirecting `<?php echo $arrival; exit; ?>` check if anything is shown in the screen

Comment: im using dynamic model

Comment: Yes , But are model attributes updated after `$model->load()` ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106464/discussion-between-ck-arjun-and-saurabh).

Answer (score 0):

Used dynamic model as no data need to save in database

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = new \yii\base\DynamicModel(['arrival','departure']);
        $model->addRule(['arrival', 'departure'], 'string', ['max' => 128]);
        $arrival = $model->arrival;
              if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
            {
                $arrival = $model->arrival;
                $departure = $model->departure;
                $model->save(); 
            }
        return $this->render('index', ['model'=>$model]);
    }
```

To get the POST method data in actionRoomsearch

```
public function actionRoomsearch()
    {

        $data = yii::$app->request->post();

        if(isset($data['DynamicModel'])) 
        { 
            $arrival = $data['DynamicModel']['arrival']; 
            $departure = $data['DynamicModel']['departure'];
        }
        return $this->render('roomsearch',['arrival' =>$arrival,'departure' => $departure]);
    }
```

To display data on page `<?php echo $arrival; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a communication between two request. I will prefer to use Flash

Note: Flash will be deleted automatically after the next request.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
     $model = new \yii\base\DynamicModel(['arrival', 'departure', 'adult', 'child']);

    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
    {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('arrival', $model->arrival);
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('departure', $model->departure);

        return $this->redirect(['roomsearch']);
    }

    return $this->render('index', ['model'=>$model]);
}
```

In the room-search page

```
public function actionRoomSearch()
{
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $arrival = $session->hasFlash('arrival') ? $session->getFlash('arrival') : null;
    $departure = $session->hasFlash('departure') ? $session->getFlash('departure') :null;

    //Do whatever you like with the data
}
```

The reason I prefer this method over $_GET is because there are times
where you have to send security sensitive data over pages and you don't 
want it revealed in the browser's address bar. 
E.g ID that is posted in an hidden field.